# c++ checking strings for equality in for loop

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, equality

I am very new to c++ and am currently working on coding a caesar cipher program which is irrelevant to this question but I can not figure out why I am getting an error with this code.

```
char alph[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMANOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string key;
cout << "Enter your key: \n";
getline(cin, key);
int numKey;
for(int j = 0; j<= 26;j++ ){
    if (alph[j] == key){
        numKey = j;
    }
}
```

There is more thats not necessary in my main function but I am getting an error with the if(alph[j] == k) statement saying "error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >'))" if somebody could tell me what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 26 characters in the alphabet, 27 loops in the program due to `<=`. That is not fatal, because of the terminating zero byte, but is most likely not what you intended.

Comment: I understand that this is a programming exercise with no real application. But seeing people assuming a 26-letter latin alphabet being sufficient for *anything* makes my skin crawl... ;-)

Comment: It baffles me as to why you think you can decide what is and isn't necessary when you don't know what the problem is?

Comment: @DevSolar: A 26-letter latin alphabet is sufficient for many, many, many things.

Comment: @DevSolar: No, it's delightfully sunny and all my code is working. Thank you for asking. And you?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Sorry, got your first comment wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a `string` with a single `char`.

If you only want to read a single character, declare a `char c` and read it with `cin >> c`

Answer (score 1):

Beside the loop overflow, you are trying to compare a character and a string, that's your issue.
Is key supposed to be only one character? If so, make it a char and it'll work much better.

Comment: You should probably elaborate a bit on "the loop overflow".

Comment: Ive stried changing it to a char and Im still getting errors. Can you tell me where and how I would go to change it.

Comment: @MatthewHanson: It is a bit difficult to show how to do it right since we do not know *what* you are trying to do. Note the question: Is `key` supposed  to be only a single character? The answer is crucial. And how did you try to "change it to char"? `key[0]` would be the way, *after* checking that `key.length() > 0`...

Comment: Yes the key is supposed to be a single character

Comment: And I just figured it out. Thanks for the help